# Visual Studio Code - type hints for JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to feed type information to the VS Code linter for JavaScript files? I have a JavaScript file and a `.d.ts` file and I'd like to have the JavaScript file parsed for type errors using this `.d.ts` file. Is that possible? If it's not possible directly in VS Code, is it possible using some other tool?

To add an example:

```
// file.d.ts
declare function f(x: number): number;

// file.js
function f(x) { return x * 2; }
f('Not a number'); // This should be an error
```

Comment: @mplungjan Maybe I wasn't precise enough in the question, but what I mean is, I'm not going to use this JavaScript file in a TypeScript project. I am going to modify this JavaScript file, but I'd like to have type checking on it if possible, since I have a `.d.ts` file for it. Should I edit the question to be more precise?

Comment: That might be useful - Although those who know what a .d.ts file is (typescript definitions?) likely know what you are asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you'll want to create a [`jsconfig.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) at the root of your project with the contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {},
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

This file tells VS Code to treat all js files (and d.ts files) as part a the same project.

However it seems that TypeScript does not merge the type declaration of `f` in the d.ts file with the actual declaration of `f` in the js file. If you comment out the implementation, you get the correct type for `f` and the expected error:

```
// @ts-check

//function f(x) { return x * 2; }

f('Not a number'); // This is an error
```

But otherwise, `f` has type `function(x: any): number`.

This seems unexpected to me and I've opened a new issue to track this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

---

Also, if you're only working in JavaScript, you can always use jsdoc comments to add type information:

```
// @ts-check

/**
 * @param {number} x 
 * @return {number}
 */
function f(x) { return x * 2; }

f('Not a number'); // This is an error
```

Comment: For me the answer was `{ "compilerOptions": { "checkJs": true } }` in `jsconfig.json`.